# how to load JSON data in select2 plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2, jvectormap

I am trying to grab the last two letters of the data attribute(data-code="US-VA" in this case VA) from the jvectormap-element of JVectormap and using it to compare with the State object from the database and load corresponding counties in select2 plugin. I am unable to set the data in the AJAX of select2. So far I have tried the following code. Thank you in advance.

HTML

```
<input type="hidden" class="tag">
```

JS:

```
$(".jvectormap-element").on("click", function(){
            data1 = $(this).data("code"); 
            $state = data1.slice(3, 5);
            $(".tag").select2({
                tags: true,
                multiple: true,
                cache: true,
                allowClear: true,
                ajax: {
                    type: "get",
                    url: http_host + '/leads/regions/counties?state=' + $state,
                    data: {state: $state},
                    dataType: "json",
                    processResults: function(data) {
                        optionsValues='';
                        for ( var i=0;i<data.length;i++ ) {
                            optionsValues += '<option>' + data[i].CountyName + '</option>';
                        }
                    }
                }

            });    console.log($(".tag").select2('data'));
        });
    });
```

The JSON data from URL:

```
[{"CountyName":"Accomack"},{"CountyName":"Albemarle"},{"CountyName":"Alexandria City"},.....]
```

Answer (score 0):

[`.slice`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_slice_array.asp) if for arrays, not for strings.

Just change `$state = data1.slice(3, 5);` to `$state = data1.substr(3, 4);`

This is zero-based... So first letter is 0.
Using [`.substr()`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_substr.asp), the 1st argument is where to start, and 2nd is where to stop **including it**.

Answer (score 0):

replace your  $state = data1.slice(3, 5); line with this

```
$strings = data1.split('-');
$state = $strings[1];
```